# Displaying a profile picture that is being fetched from Github

Tags: dom

I am a newbie and am attempting to display an image that is from my Github profile vs hardcoding it into the HTML. Currently, I have coded the following and the object is being displayed in my Javascript console.

```
const APIURL = 'https://api.github.com/users/'

getUser('JetimLee')


async function getUser(username) {
  try {
    const {
      data
    } = await axios(APIURL + username)

    console.log(data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)

 } 
}
```

My question is - how do I get the image from the profile to be displayed? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You have an avatar_url field, set it's value as source of an image tag in your html.

Example:

```
const data = await axios('link');
const imgTag = document.getElementById('git-user-id');
imgTag.setAttribute('src', data.avatar_url);
```

Comment: you're welcome. also try checking some DOM methods in JS on MDN)
and check this as correct if it helps) thank you

Comment: I think I marked it as correct! 
As for displaying my name, would I follow the same idea that you have laid out here?

Comment: Hello, yes, the logic is the same, but you deal with simple text, so you would need to change `innerText` or `innerHtml` of an HTML element, instead of setting src attribute. And no, you did not mark it as correct, to do this click a tick button on the left of my answer. Thank you)